# QT - QOpenGLShader: how to use glsl 3.3 core

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a QT-setup for my program and want to use glsl version "core 330" shaders.
My GLWidget is a QOpenGLWidget object.
After I created my widget I run following code:

```
glWidget = new GLWidget;

QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
format.setVersion(3, 3);
format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
glWidget->setFormat(format);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

Now my question is, how do I enable the modern GLSL for my following shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 uvs;
out vec2 uv;
void main(){

  uv = uvs;
  gl_Position = vec4(vertex,1.0);
}
```

I searched in StackOverflow and used Google, but I can't find a working explanation.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**
Additional information:

- I'm using the QT 5.6 alpha version

**Edit #2**
I create my shader with following code:

vertexShader = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Vertex);
    std::string str = ReadFile("./Shader/VidIt/videoShow.vert");

```
vertexShader->compileSourceCode(str.c_str());
fragmentShader = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Fragment);
str = ReadFile("./Shader/VidIt/videoShow.frag");
vertexShader->compileSourceCode(str.c_str());

program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
program->addShader(vertexShader);
program->addShader(fragmentShader);
program->link();
```

this code though does not compile my shader and I get the following compiling error:

> QOpenGLShader::compile(Vertex): ERROR: 0:2: 'core' : invalid version
>   directive

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I enable" it? How you create a shader doesn't change.

Comment: @NicolBolas: see the new edit... sorry for the misunderstandings